# how to split one column into another by multiple conditions?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have to create an `awk` script to achieve the following transformation:

1. Column order is random
2. There is no fixed structure. actually this is a big issue
3. The `FLAG` column must be splitt in `FLAG1` and `FLAG2`
4. `FLAG1` and `FLAG2` are filled given the following conditions:

   ```
   if the VAL is ":" then NUM is null
   if the VAL is ":" and FLAG "c" then NUM is null and FLAG1 is "c"
   if the VAL is ":" and FLAG "u" then NUM is null and FLAG2 is "u"
   if the VAL is "14,385" and FLAG "d" then NUM is "14385" and FLAG(both) is null
   if the VAL is "14,385" and FLAG "du" then NUM is "14385" and FLAG2 is "u"
   if the VAL is ":" and FLAG "cd" then NUM is null and FLAG1 is "c"
   if the VAL is ":" and FLAG "bc" then NUM is null and FLAG1 is "c" and FLAG2 is "b"
   if the VAL is ":" and FLAG "z" then NUM is 0 and FLAG2 is "z"
   ```

The `csv` input file is:

```
"PRIM",  "TRD",   "GTR",   "VAL",   "FLAG"
"TPP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   c
"TCP",   "T5-78", "HT",    "12,385",  c
"TZP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   z
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   z
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   cd
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   du
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    "12,524,652",  dfg
```

The output `.dat` file should look like this:

```
PRIM    TRD GTR NUM FLAG1   FLAG2
TPP T5-78   HT  null    c   null
TCP T5-78   HT  12385   c   null
TZP T5-78   HT  0   null    z
TNP T5-78   HT  0   null    z
TNP T5-78   HT  null    c   null
TNP T5-78   HT  null    null    u
TNP T5-78   HT  12524652    null    dfg
```

The code I have tried doesn't work properly as only the first 3 requirements are met while the 4th just doesn't work.

```
BEGIN {
      FS=","; OFS="\t";
      a["PRIM"]=1;a["TRD"]=1;a["GTR"]=1;a["VAL"]=1;a["FLAG"]=1;
    }
    NR==1 {

   { $a["VAL"] = "NUMB" ; $a["FLAG"] = "FLAG1" ; $5 = "FLAG2" ; print ; next }
    $a["VAL"]=="12,385" && $a["FLAG"] == "d"  { $a["VAL"] = "14385" ; $a["FLAG"] = $5 = "" }
    $a["VAL"]=="12,385" && $a["FLAG"] == "du" { $a["VAL"] = "14385" ; $a["FLAG"] = "" ; $9 = "u" }
    $a["VAL"] != ":" { print ; next }
    $a["FLAG"] == "z" { $a["VAL"] = "0" ; $a["FLAG"] = "" ; $5 = "z" }
     $a["FLAG"] != "z" { $a["VAL"] = "" }

        $NF=substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1);
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a) a[$i]=i;
    }
    {   print $a["PRIM"],$a["TRD"],$a["GTR"],NR==1?"NUM":$a["VAL"],
        NR==1?"FLAG1"OFS"FLAG2":($a["FLAG"]?""OFS$a["FLAG"]:$a["FLAG"]);
```

---

Here is the latest code which I think it will work. the problem now which I cannot solve is that the last value (FLAG2) is printed on the second line. I tried to put `OFS` but it doesn't fix the problem. Could you please tell me what is wrong in this case.

```
BEGIN {
FS=","; 
OFS="\t";
a["PRIM"]=1;
a["TRD"]=1;
a["GTR"]=1;
a["VAL"]=1;
a["FLAG"]=1;
a["FLAG1"]=1;
a["FLAG2"]=1;
}

NR==1 {
    $NF=substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1);
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
#if($i in a) 
a[$i]=i;

a["FLAG1"] = i;
a["FLAG2"]=i;
a["FLAG1"] = a["FLAG"];  # just for testing and it is ok
a["FLAG2"] = a["FLAG"];  # just for testing and it is ok

}

{   

print $a["PRIM"],$a["TRD"],$a["GTR"],NR==1?"NUM":$a["VAL"],
    NR==1?"FLAG1":$a["FLAG1"],NR==1?"FLAG2":$a["FLAG2"];
```

}

the output is something like

```
PRIM    TRD GTR NUM FLAG1   FLAG2
TPP T5-78   HT  null    c
   null
TCP T5-78   HT  12385   c
   null
TZP T5-78   HT  0   null
    z
```

---

After so many advices this is my last version but it is still unsuccesful... Now when I'm adding if statements for fulfilling the requirements above, nothing happens. I believe the if statements either are not correct nor putted in the right place. 
printing the values if NR>1 is a catastropha..
could you pls tell me what is wrong with my script? I have to admit that I started with this awk 3 days ago and so far it is painful...the problem is that I have should have finished this script since last week

```
BEGIN {
FS=",";
OFS="\t";

a["PRIM"]=1;
a["TRD"]=1;
a["GTR"]=1;
a["VAL"]=1;
a["FLAG"]=1;
a["FLAG1"]=1;
a["FLAG2"]=1;
}

NR==1 {

$NF=substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1);
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
#if($i in a)
a[$i]=i;

#a["FLAG1"] = a[i];
#a["FLAG2"]=a[i];

a["FLAG1"] = a["FLAG"];
a["FLAG2"] = a["FLAG"];
}

{
#initialisation of the new flags
a["FLAG1"]=="";
a["FLAG2"]=="";
}

#MY IF STATEMENTS GO HERE   - TEST MODE   

a["FLAG"] == "cd"   {a["FLAG1"]= "c"}
a["FLAG"] == "du"   {a["FLAG2"]= "u"}

{  
#print header
print $a["PRIM"],$a["TRD"],$a["GTR"],NR==1?"NUM":$a["VAL"], NR==1?"FLAG1":$a["FLAG1"],NR==1?"FLAG2":$a["FLAG2"];
}

#print content
NR>1
{
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
#if($i in a)
a[$j]=j;

#a["FLAG1"] = a[i];
#a["FLAG2"]=a[i];

a["FLAG1"] = a["FLAG"];
a["FLAG2"] = a["FLAG"];
}
#MY IF STATEMENTS GO HERE   - TEST MODE   

a["FLAG"] == "cd"   {a["FLAG1"]= "c"}
a["FLAG"] == "du"   {a["FLAG2"]= "u"}

{
print $a["PRIM"],$a["TRD"],$a["GTR"],$a["VAL"], $a["FLAG1"], $a["FLAG2"]
}
```

Comment: awk is not that smart about CSV files. It can't tell when a comma occurs within quotes ("VAL" value) versus outside of quotes (awk's FS variable). I'd recommend using a language with a proper CSV parser.

Comment: Yes you are right but on a short term I need a solution for awk. I have to keep what I have. Unfortunately I'm not an expert so I'm almost dying..

Comment: The sample text is not actually comma-separated. Is that your real input?

Comment: yes you are right. I corrected it

Comment: is anyone able to help me? the problem is in the conditions. If I remove them no error appears and only the splitting is working fine..

Comment: is someone able to tell me what is wrong with my last script?

Answer (score 2):

This requires **all input fields** to have double quotes.

```
$ echo '"PRIM",  "TRD",   "GTR",   "VAL",   "FLAG"
"TPP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   "c"
"TCP",   "T5-78", "HT",    "12,385",  "c"
"TZP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   "z"
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   "z"
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   "cd"
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    ":",   "du"
"TNP",   "T5-78", "HT",    "12,524,652",  "dfg"' | 
awk -F '",[ \t]*"' '
    { sub(/^"/, "", $1); sub(/"$/, "", $NF)}
    NR == 1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) col[$i] = i
        print "PRIM TRD GTR NUM FLAG1 FLAG2"
        next
    } 
    {
        f = $col["FLAG"] 
        v = $col["VAL"]; gsub(/,/, "", v) 
        num = "null"; flag1 = "null"; flag2 = "null"
    }
    v == ":"      &&  f == "c"   {flag1 = "c"}
    v == ":"      &&  f == "u"   {flag2 = "u"} 
    v == "14385"  &&  f == "d"   {num = $4}
    v == "14385"  &&  f == "du"  {num = $4; flag2 = "u"}
    v == ":"      &&  f == "cd"  {flag1 = "c"}
    v == ":"      &&  f == "bc"  {flag1 = "c"; flag2 = "b"}
    v == ":"      &&  f == "z"   {num = 0; flag2 = "z"}
    {print $col["PRIM"],$col["TRD"],$col["GTR"],num,flag1,flag2}
'
```

```
PRIM TRD GTR NUM FLAG1 FLAG2
TPP T5-78 HT null c null
TCP T5-78 HT null null null
TZP T5-78 HT null null z
TNP T5-78 HT null null z
TNP T5-78 HT null c null
TNP T5-78 HT null null null
TNP T5-78 HT null null null
```

My output does not look like yours. Review your specifications and make sure the sample input is sufficient to cover them.

Comment: the columns are not coming always in the same order. for this reason I used arrays. $4 or $5 might be always different. double quotes are always there as I understood

Comment: Fixed the floating columns.

Comment: I did exactly like you mentioned. is formatting ok but NUM, FLAG1 and FLAG2 are all NULL. nothing inside these fields. the values that were coming for NUM were even deleted. maybe in the last print something is needed. It is my first time when I have to deal with these kind of...

Comment: I think I'm very close. at the last column value is moving to the next line. the print is the problem but I don't get it. the values are correct. what could be wrong with this print:                 print $a["PRIM"],$a["TRD"],$a["GTR"],NR==1?"NUM":$a["VAL"],
NR==1?"FLAG1":$a["FLAG1"],NR==1?"FLAG2":$a["FLAG2"];

Comment: You are only *setting* the values when NR == 1. What do you think you should do for all the other lines? Re-read my answer and notice that I have one NR==1 rule and three "everywhere" blocks. Note also my use of `-F` to set FS to a complicated regex to match a comma between quotes: `FS=","` is too simple

Comment: what should I change in my code? I don't understand...removing "NR==1"?

Comment: or putting NR>1 together with another print? your solution doesn't work as I already mentioned

Comment: Because of lack of knowledge I would like to explain me what means -F '",[ \t]*"'  and how should I replace in my code?                                                                  FS=","; 
OFS="\t"; . I know that is a field separator but I don't understand how should I replace my code?

Comment: The `-F` option sets the `FS` variable. So use the same value to set FS in the BEGIN block

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51515/discussion-between-user3569977-and-glenn-jackman)

Answer (score 0):

the final working solution is exactly like this one:

```
BEGIN {
FS=",";
OFS="\t";
}
{
# delete the carriage return character from windows. the magic part
sub(/\015$/,"")
sub(/^"/, "", $1)
 sub(/"$/, "", $NF)
}

NR==1{

        #$NF=substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1);
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) col[$i]=i
        print "PRIM TRD GTR NUM FLAG1 FLAG2"
        next
}

{

        f=$col["FLAG"];
        v=$col["NUM"];
        gsub(/,/, "", v)
        gsub(/,/, "", f)
       flag1 = "";
       flag2 = "";

   if(substr(v,1,1) == ":" && substr(f,1,1) == "c")
    {
      flag1 = "c";
      flag2 ="";
    }

if ( ! ( substr(f,1,1) == "dz" || substr(f,1,1) =="du" || substr(f,1,1) =="cd" || substr(f,1,1) =="c" || substr(f,1,1) =="z") || substr(f,1,1) =="u" || substr(f,1,1) =="d" ) )
    {
      flag1 = "";
      flag2 =f;

    }

     print $col["PRIM"],$col["TRD"],$col["GTR"],v,flag1,flag2 ;


}
```