# How can I split a column by multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, split

## Background

I have a table of some 900 000 individuals (census of 1875). I am creating lists of criminals, and am trying to find children following their parents in prison. To do this, I am using two tables: table 1 contains all criminals; table 2 contains every individual. I want to search for people in table 2 that are listed below those in table 1, and are aged 0–15 years of age.

## Preparation

In cleaning my tables, I have made a selection of roughly 6 000 that could not be easily selected and/or cleaned. The main parts of the data structure is as follows:

```
These collectively identify each individual           Not part of table
┌───────┴───────┐                                     ┌───────────┴───────────┐
ID1  ID2 ID3  ID4 FNAME   LNAME        BYEAR          *comment*
0515 004 0072 006 Ole     Jacobsen     1825@1826      usable
0515 004 0072 007 Gunhild Thorsdatter  1831@1835      possibly usable
0515 004 0075 010 Hans    Johnsden     1875@1865      unusable
0515 004 0099 001 Marit   Jakobsdatter 1832??@1837??  usable
0515 004 0102 193 Arne    Olsen        1836 %1805%    usable
0515 004 0102 194 Rasmus  Pedersen     1876!!         usable after corrections
```

### Explanation:

- An @ sign indicates ''or''
- A ?? indicates uncertainty
- A !! indicates the source actually contained this wrongful information
- %[text]% indicates text was stricken in the source

## Method and Main Question

What I plan to do, is list every individual in which `BYEAR` is listed as `YYYY@YYYY` (year1[or]year2); I could do this with `like "*@*"`. I would, however, also like to have the information in BYEAR split into three columns: `BYEAR1` `BYEARJUNK` (see note 3) `BYEAR2`. From these columns, I would be able to calculate the age difference, with clean numbers, thereby finding the individuals on which I could actually perform further studies.

So I repeat and clarify my question from the heading: How would I split the BYEAR column into three (or more) columns, with @ or space as delimiters?

## Notes

### 1

Others have asked similar questions, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278665/how-to-split-one-column-into-another-by-multiple-conditions) is about Unix and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942153/how-to-split-a-column-value-to-a-in-condition) answers the question by not splitting the data, which I need to do to perform calculations (and so others can easily reproduce my method).

### 2

I have added the Oracle tag. I am, however, presently working locally, but would in the future need to to the same operations towards the server.

### 3

The above does not clearly state how the junk column should be filled. It’s function is to list everything from the initial to the final separator. Here are the basic rules:

#### Approach 1

- If there is a @, `BYEAR` can be considered to have only one separator. `BYEAR1` would be populated by everything before the @ and `BYEAR2` by everything following it; `BYEARJUNK` would contain only the @.
- If there is a space following the first year – e.g. ‘1802?? eller 1808’ or ‘1802?? eller ant. 1808’, `BYEARJUNK` should be populated by respectively ‘ eller ’ and ‘ eller ant. ’ (including the spaces).
- But what if there are spaces *and* an @ sign, e.g. ‘1802?? eller 1803@1808’? In such cases, I would count the first space as the initial separator and the (final) @ as the final separator. In other words: `BYEAR1`: ‘1802??’; `BYEARJUNK`: ‘ eller 1803@’; `BYEAR2`: ‘1808’.

#### Approach 2

Simply like this: @ and space is always considered a separator; the number of `BYEARJUNK` columns to create, would therefore be equal to the field with the most number of words (minus two). This method is probably the easiest and best approach, as one could easily isolate the data of interest afterwards. `BYEAR1` and `BYEAR2` should always be the first and last part of the field’s data.

Comment: msaccess have a [split function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/split.php) but have you consider use a modern db like postgresql or mysql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza MS Access is a RAD tool with any number of backend dbs.

Comment: You can use a user defined function including split in sql.

Comment: @Fionnuala I didnt said couldnt work, but after thinking on how easy would be do the same in postgres I have to give the suggestion.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza SQL Server, Oracle and Postgres all work as back ends to MS Access, unless it is stated that the ACE or Jet are the database, you cannot know. These days, I mostly use SQL Server as the back end.

Comment: @Fionnuala, Sorry you lose me. If the question is ms-access doesnt mean the db is access? if the backend is a different one then the tags are wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127315/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: I don't quite understand how you want to fill the `BYEARJUNK` column. E.g. how would `1832??@1837??` be split? Or `1836 %1805%`

Comment: I am working in MS Access, yes, and the 2007 version to be clear about that. Switching is not an option.

Comment: @Andre Your selected example would be split as such: `BYEAR1`1832??, `BYEARJUNK` @, `BYEAR2` 1837??.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I’ll look into the `split` function. Maybe that solves it?

Comment: Still not clear. So `BYEARJUNK` would always contain only the "@"? Then why not ignore it? It would be best if you add a table to your question, with various examples of original `BYEAR` and the 3 output columns with expected result. Use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for the table (build in Excel or directly there).

Comment: @Andre Sorry, I was to quick on the trigger. I have update my post discussing your question briefly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a dataset that has been cleaned, i.e. there are always four digits followed by a separator (here @) followed by four digits, the following code solves the problem. Note: I have changed the names of the fields to `L[eft]BYEAR` and `R[ight]BYEAR` and have not created a column for junk, *as the data have been cleaned*.

```
SELECT
LEFT ([BYEAR], 4) AS LBYEAR,
RIGHT([BYEAR], 4) AS RBYEAR,
(LBYEAR-RBYEAR)   AS ΣBYEARDIFF,
*

FROM [mytable]

WHERE BYEAR like "*@*";
```

This creates three columns:

- `LBYEAR` finds the first four characters (hopefully digits) in the column `BYEAR`.
- `RBYEAR` finds the last four characters (hopefully digits) in the column `BYEAR`.
- `ΣBYEARDIFF` calculates the difference.

The final column is very useful, as it returns error for fields where it could extract the correct data, i.e. fields in which the data had not been cleaned. Output example:

```
LBYEAR  RBYEAR  ΣBYEARDIFF  PERSNR  FORNVN      ETTNVN          FAAR
1857    1847    10          005     Dorthea     Evensen         1857@1847
1845    1847    -2          002     Katharine   Olsdatter Ovren 1838@1837
22.0    1825    #Error      002     Boel Karin  Amundsen        22.06@07.1825
1857    1867    -10         008     Thrine  Andersen            1857@1867
1858    1857    1           027     Karl Georg  Syvertsen       1858@1857
```

Using this column, one could – depending on the requirements of the study – choose which rows to include in the final cleanup step using first a `WHERE ΣBYEARDIFF BETWEEN n and m`, e.g. `WHERE ΣBYEARDIFF BETWEEN -2 and 2` to insert the accepted data into a new table, then run an update query (see below) to remove everything past the first four digits (in this case characters, which happen to be digits).

The code:

```
UPDATE [T with accepted data]

SET BYEAR = left(BYEAR, 4)
WHERE BYEAR like "????*";
```

Answer (score -1):

Are there always 2 dates separated by @?

```
left(byear,instr(byear,"@")-1)
```

will give you the caracters before the @

```
mid(byear,instr(byear,"@")+1)
```

will give you the characters after the @

Comment: In some cases, I could get something like this: `1836??@1835?? %18??%`, which would not be uncommon. I have decided to ignore stricken text though; it does not matter whether or not there was something stricken in the source to me. In other words, the answer to your question is yes: If there is a text written with a @, there will always be just one to the left and one to the right. Your answer does not, however, show how to split the contents into multiple columns, which would be important for me, so I could see all the parts (there could be text, like ‘1837 eller 1839’ (eller = or).

Comment: I have to correct myself. Going through the data, I’ve found that there are plenty of cases of years being written as e.g. 1836-1837. This is yet another reason why I would need to split the information in multiple columns. It’s even worse when I get hits like 183??6??@18??7 (i.e. ‘eighteen-maybe-thirty-maybe-six or 18-unknown-decade-seven’).